# slick update fields dynamically

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I get a form from a `Play` controller

```
class CustomerTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Customer]("customer", tag) {
   def id = column[Long]("id")
   ...
   def * = ...
}

case class Customer(
   id: Long,
   remarkName: String
   ...
)

case class CustomerUpdateForm(
  id: Long,
  remarkName: Option[String],
  realName: Option[String],
  birth: Option[Date],
  address: Option[String],
  phone: Option[String],
  qq: Option[String],
  email: Option[String])
```

And I want to update the database with `nonEmpty` fields  of the form, here's how I did

```
def updateField(form: CustomerUpdateForm) = {
  def updateField0[T](
    field: CustomerTable => Column[T],
    value: T) = {
     customerTable
      .filer(_.id, form.id)
      .map(c => field(c) -> c.gmtModified)
      .update(value -> new Date)
  }
  var updated = 0
  if (form.remarkName.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.remarkName, form.remarkName)
    updated = updated + 1
  if(form.realName.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.realName, form.realName)
    updated = updated + 1
  if(form.birth.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.birth, form.birth)
    updated = updated + 1
  if(form.address.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.address, form.address)
    updated = updated + 1
  if(form.phone.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.phone, form.phone)
    updated = updated + 1
  if(form.qq.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.qq, form.qq)
    updated = updated + 1
  if(form.email.nonEmpty)
    updateField0(_.email, form.email)
    updated = updated + 1
   if(updated  > 1) 1 else 0
}
```

Can I update those fields by one time ?

Comment: +1, I'm also curious about this. One way could be to get the full row from the database as a `CustomerTableRow` object, then using reflection you could check if form fields are `Some` or `None` and modify the row object accordingly, in the end you could simply use the update function. Just a guess though, never actually used reflections and I'm not sure it's possible in this case.

Comment: CustomerTable is a case class right? Do you preserve the same names in the form and in your CustomerTable columns objects?

Comment: @dirceusemighini `CustomerTable` is a `Table` I have update my question

Comment: @jilen I still don't understanding your question. You wan't to use the form to update the database value, or you wan't to use a selected value from the database, to create a form?

Comment: @dirceusemighini look at the `updateField` method. I want to update my database with the non-empty field in form

Comment: I am also interested in this, what did you end up with?

Comment: @YuanfeiZhu  There's a chance, but really complicated way.  This project may provide some idea https://github.com/scalax/hf